JAVA-Selenium-Unable to find version of CDP to use for 124.0.6367.202
Error Message :
May 10, 2024 11:00:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch WARNING: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 124 May 10, 2024 11:00:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$5 WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for 124.0.6367.202. You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.20.0 where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
This error will be occurred in my maven project.
I have added dependency, but it has not resolved.
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-devtools-v86</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-7</version>
        </dependency>

Chrome Version : 124.0.6367.202  Selenium Version : selenium-server-4.20.0

try using 4.20 as suggested instead of
4.0.0-alpha-7  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/4.20.0  This should fix the issue as the driver would be automatically downloaded based on your browser version (unless you have some internet firewall restriction applied on your machine)
